# Magento 2.3.7 / Where magento generate version output text (e.g Magento CLI 2.3.7)?

Tags: magento2

when developer getting magento version using CLI command:

```
php bin/magento -V
```

Where is in the code magento generate the output of this command ? Does magento version is some defined constant in vendor folder code ? or in database ? Please give me the path or database table name and field name.

Answer (score 0):

You may debug this information in the **vendor/symfony/console/Application.php**
Check following methods

```
public function doRun(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
  if (true === $input->hasParameterOption(['--version', '-V'], true)) {
  $output->writeln($this->getLongVersion());

  return 0;
}

public function getLongVersion()
{
  if ('UNKNOWN' !== $this->getName()) {
  if ('UNKNOWN' !== $this->getVersion()) {
     return sprintf('%s <info>%s</info>', $this->getName(), $this->getVersion());
}
```